# Nginx PHP Upload progress working?

Tags: php, nginx

It is a known fact with uploads in Nginx the server fills the buffer and then sends the file to PHP.

This normally means that upload progress for PHP never worked (not to mention fcgi) however, I have just upgraded to version 1.4.4 of Nginx and it...well, works.

PHP is able to keep track of the upload. I tested it a couple of times to make sure.

If I understand it correctly this might mean that I am no longer receiving the benefits that Nginx would give me in file uploads (such as async IO) or am I wrong, has there been some progress on this front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I recon I actually know the answer and it is quite simple.

Nginx, without the upload modules you can install, will try and buffer it in memory. When the allocated memory for its process is used up it will actually dump that to a PHP process.

It is at this time that PHP can understand upload progress etc, is when Nginx can only no longer hold the entire file in memory.