# Nginx Upload Progress Module on Windows

Tags: php, windows, symfony, file-upload, nginx

I'm looking for a file upload with a nice JavaScript progress bar. For development, I run nginx 1.9.11 with PHP 7 (FastCGI) on **Windows.**

Everybody says that any PHP solution will not work, since nginx is buffering the upload and only pass it to PHP when it's finished (i.e. 100%). So - to be honest - I didn't even try it ;-)
Sources:

- http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php
- http://bytes.jocarter.co.uk/post/41709800721/server-side-file-upload-progress
- [Nginx PHP Upload progress working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691287/nginx-php-upload-progress-working)

The solution seems to be the [NGINX Upload Progress Module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload_progress/). Unfortunately I can't find any Windows binaries anywhere :-(

Is there a chance to get this module running on Windows? Any ideas anybody?

P.S.: I'm using Symfony 2.8.2 - but I guess that's irrelevant for that matter ;-)

Comment: Use AJAX Upload. E.g. blueimp minimal fileupload. You can then make a progessbar with JS. I don't use Nginx' upload module, so I can't say if there is something in PHP's session superglobal.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, was at work. :) Blueimp Fileupload is a jQuery plugin to allow easy file uploads via AJAX, so this works with any webserver as it is clientside. Even with the minimal setup you can make a progressbar, just check it out. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: It works for me on localhost. You don't need input from the server as you can just get the information directly with JS.

Comment: Thanks for insisting!! :-) Until now I didn't understand that the Session Upload Progress and the Ajax/JavaScript way are two **different** approaches to this problem. blueimp now does work for me. Please post your comments as answer, so I can mark it as accepted :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something server independly, you can just upload the files with AJAX and then make a progressbar in Javascript.

A good example of a jquery file upload plugin would be blueimp jquery file upload. https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Here's a good tutorial for the JavaScript part (to replace the jQuery plugin): http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-file-upload-progress-bar/